# print \n without going to newline in python3

Tags: python

hi I want to  print this

```
print('hi my name is \njack')
```

but don't want to go to the next line I want output to be like `hi my name is \njack`now with a newline

Comment: Can you please clarify the question?  There is an `end` parameter in the `print()` function which might be of use.

Comment: @broccoli2303 No, that will output quotes as well. The OP wants to output a string, not a string representation of a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624041/print-n-or-newline-characters-as-part-of-the-output-on-terminal/31624058 see this also

Comment: @Bava how will that help? The `\n` is in ***the middle*** of the string and needed to be ignored

Comment: @Tomerikoo - Agreed mate.  Just shows I didn’t fully understand the question.

Answer (score 3):

Use an extra \ in the print statement. Something like:

```
print('hi my name is \\njack')
```

This will output

```
hi my name is \njack
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **raw** string to print everything inside a string. As for your example:

```
print(r"hi my name is \njack")
```

The output will be

```
hi my name is \njack
```

Comment: print(repr("hi my name is \njack") should give you the same behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Define the string using [raw literal syntax instead of regular literal syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

```py
>>> print(r'hi my name is \njack')
hi my name is \njack
```

This preserves practically all escape sequences literally.