# Print out carriage return or new line characters

Tags: python

Hello i have a string that looks like this

```
This is a test string
This is the second line
```

I am trying to print out both lines and see the actual \r or \n character

so it would output like this

`This is a test string\n This is the second line\n`

i tried just print(string_variable) but that gives me the string without the "\n" or "\r"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print "\n" or newline characters as part of the output on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624041/print-n-or-newline-characters-as-part-of-the-output-on-terminal)

Comment: Please search before posting a question (and show what you've searched for).

Comment: But there are no carriage return or newline characters in your sample string

Comment: @Pingu that was just a formatting problem. They used single backticks to enclose the string, and single backticks don't keep line breaks. I've just changed to triple backticks. (Even like this, I guess the message is to be understood as "I have a string that, when printed, looks like this"

Comment: It's hard to call your first example a string, rather than the visible output of *some* string being written to the terminal. Perhaps you have `s = 'foo\nbar\n'`, and instead of using `print(s)`, you want `print(repr(s))`? (Though you may not want the quotes that are included in the representation of `s`; perhaps `print(repr(s).strip("'"))` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what is exactly your objective, two ways I can think of.

```py
s="one\ntwo\r\nthree\n\rxour\rf"
print(s.encode()) # print not a string but a bytes array, (b'...') containing the bytes encoding the string. 
print(s.__repr__()) # print the same thing the interactive interpreter shows when you just type `s` on a line.
```

The second one (as `__repr__` generally is) shows the string as you should type it. That is, you can copy&paste the output of `__repr__()` into a python code. So, it prints exactly what you see on the first line of my code.

The first one prints the actual bytes that are used to encode the string, that is, for example, the actual bytes that are sent to a terminal to make it print that string (according to default encoding. You can specify encoding as parameter. But afaik, none, and certainly none of the most common one, such as `utf8`, `latin1`, `cp850`, influence the way `\n` or `\r` are encoded).